# C# Populating a listview from a List

Tags: c#, wpf

So in my C# (WPF) application I use a form to populate a list of patients. I need these patients to show up in a listview, as they're added.

```
public class Patients
{
    public string lastname;
    public string firstname;
    public string rm;
    public int age;
    public string notes;
    public int  status; 

    public Patients(string lastname, string firstname, int age, string rm, string notes, int status)
    {
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.status = status;
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public List<Patients> newPatientList = new List<Patients>();

    public void AddNewPatient(string lastname, string firstname, int age, string rm, string notes, int status)
    {

        newPatientList.Add(new Patients(lastname, firstname, age, rm, notes, status));
     }
}
```

This adds patients fine to the list.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding newPatientList}" x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="RM #" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding rm}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastname}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firstname}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding status}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I'm trying to bind the data to the list, but it does not populate.

Comment: This is because `List<T>` does not notify the bound control that its collection has changed. try using an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`

Comment: ... and a ViewModel instead of stuffing the Model into the View code.

Comment: Offtopic, it's very weird to call your class `Patients`, when an instance of this class represents a _single_ patient. I have a sneaky suspision that you've used the plural because of `List<Patients>`, but you'll be better off using `List<Patient>`. Even though it sounds less correct when addressing a list, using the singular for your class name will sound much more correct when you're dealing with the class _when it is **not** wrapped in a list_. You can already see it happening in your example, the method `AddNewPatient()` (singular) does the following: `.Add(new Patients())` (plural)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use an `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` :

```
public ObservableCollection<Patients> newPatientList = new ObservableCollection<Patients>();
```

Thre reason your control is not updating, is that `List` cannot tell the control that its collection has changed, leaving the control oblivious of when to update itself.

`ObservableCollection` will notify the control whenever its collection changes, and all items will be rendered.

Keep in mind, that changing any property of the items inside the collection still will not notify the control, but i think that is ouside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

wpf bindings require *properties*. `Patients` class declares *fields*.

instead of

```
public string lastname;
```

make

```
public string lastname { get;set; }
```

---

also according to common naming convention it should better be

```
public string LastName { get;set; }
```

don't forget to fix bindings, they are case-sensitive

```
"{Binding LastName}"
```

---

you have similar issue with `newPatientList` field.

```
public List<Patients> newPatientList = new List<Patients>();
```

and don't forget to set Window `DataContext`. Bindings look up values from DataContext. if it is null, there won't be any values displayed