# C# WPF What's wrong with this template?

Tags: wpf, templates

I'm trying to create a new window (child of MainWindow) that will display different numbers of rows with data each time. I used the following template that I copied from a wpf template tutorial. I've checked that the data are right and I can project them right with a MessageBox.Show window but I can't make them appear as bound properties. Here is the xaml...

```
<ListView x:Name="listUnits" x:FieldModifier="public"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Id:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding pu_Id}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding pu_unitName}" Width="Auto"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

So although pu_unitName contains the data, they're are displayed in the new window.

The binding is done in the constructor:

```
public partial class ChooseUnit : Window
{
    public ChooseUnit(List<XML_Handler.PrUnits> thisList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listUnits.ItemsSource = thisList;
    }

}
```

The PrUnits is a class which contains variables including pu_id and pu_unitName. So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: wpf doesn't bind to *variables*, it binds to *properties*. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584249/c-sharp-populating-a-listview-from-a-list

Comment: How is the PrUnits class implemented?

Comment: PrUnits contains a series of variables (not properties). pu_id is an int and pu_unitName is a string. As the other guys pointed out I should have added a get/set to make them properties. I hadn't realized it was necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only bind to public *properties*, you need to make sure that `pu_Id` and `pu_UnitName` are properties (and not fields) of the `PrUnits` class. Then your bindings will work.

Also note that this is not a binding:

```
listUnits.ItemsSource = thisList;
```

In general, you would set the `DataContext` of the parent window to an instance of a view model class and bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` to a property that returns the `List<XML_Handler.PrUnits>`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listUnits" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}">
...
```

Comment: mm8: but it works as it is (without setting the DataContext). What's the difference (or advantage) if I set it as well? I've bound ItemsSource to a List (not a property) which contains the properties I want to use.

Comment: It is just a common design pattern known as MVVM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx. It is the recommended design pattern for developing XAML based UI apps. You should learn it if you are serious about WPF. But in this case, it doesn't really matter :)

Answer (score 0):

In your .cs:

```
public partial class ChooseUnit : Window
{
    public ChooseUnit(List<XML_Handler.PrUnits> thisList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = thisList;
    }
}
```

What this does it assigns the data context of your window to the list of itemsa you are trying to pass. At this point every element in that window will have access to the passed in list.
And then in your XAML do this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listUnits" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" x:FieldModifier="public"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
```

This allows us to use binding as the entire window has access to the list. Hence `ItemsSource="{Binding .}"`.

**EDIT**
Reading more into your question and thanks to [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506454/ash) your class needs to expose Properties with INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented.
This interface is expected by the WPF framework so it can subscribe to the changed events and update the UI.