# How do I properly set my itemsource in WPF to display my ObservableCollection items?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, xaml

I have this project where I am trying to figure out how to add things to the listview and then later be able to delete them. But I cant seem to get the itemsource to bind unless I hardcode it. How do I do it in the XAML?

This adds a item to the listview

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<myItem> Item;
        const string pattern = @"((.*)) (.*) left the game";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAppend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Item = new ObservableCollection<myItem>() { new myItem() { Username = "Prabhat" } };
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = Item;
        }
    }
```

However if I remove the hardcoded itemsource it doesnt add it even if I add Itemsource={Binding Item} to ym XAML

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="107" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Username}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Name="tbConent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="10,122,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497"/>
        <Button Name="btnAppend" Click="btnAppend_Click" Content="Append" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
```

EDIT

Class

```
public class myItem
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT 2

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Listviewssssssssssssss
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<myItem> Item { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAppend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Item = new ObservableCollection<myItem>() { new myItem() { Username = "Prabhat" } };
            lvUsers.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Populating a listview from a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584249/c-sharp-populating-a-listview-from-a-list)

Comment: [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) comes in  handy when working with WPF and especially XAML  Bindings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Item` a public property:

```
public ObservableCollection<myItem> Item { get; private set; }
```

And you can bind to it like this:

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" ...>
```

Make sure that `myItem` is a public type:

```
public class myItem { ... }
```

Or you could set the `DataContext` of the window to itself:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<myItem> Item { get; private set; }
    const string pattern = @"((.*)) (.*) left the game";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Item = new ObservableCollection<myItem>() { new myItem() { Username = "Prabhat" } };
    }
}
```

...and bind to the source collection directly:

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Item}" ...>
```

You should also probably consider renaming the property to "Item**s**" since it is a collection.

**Edit:**

Edit: If you intend to set the `Item` property dynamically after the initial binding, you also need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise change notifications:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<myItem> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<myItem> Item
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAppend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item = new ObservableCollection<myItem>() { new myItem() { Username = "Prabhat" } };
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the modofer gave me this Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'ObservableCollection<myItem>' is less accessible than field 'MainWindow.Item'

Comment: Its still not adding the Username to the listview hm

Comment: Is Username a public property of the myItem class?

Comment: Yes sir, ill update the questions so you can see the class

Comment: Could you please also post the current definiton of MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Comment: You need to set the Item property in the constructor or implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: But if I add the item property in the main constructor how will I use my button to add a new user?

Comment: That seems to have the same effect, doesnt seem to add the user.

Comment: Nvm changed the ItemSource in my XAML

Comment: How come it doesnt add multiple ones if the same name if I click the button multiple times?

Comment: Like it doesnt append it just changed the property value

Comment: You are setting the property to new collection each time. But please ask a new question if you have a new issue.

Comment: I will post a new question in a moment, I need to get some food after working on this project for so long. Really appriciate the help so far!